# Automatic conversion currency to local one with ebay sdk

Tags: python, ebay-sdk

I use

```
response = api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', {'keywords': keyWords,
                                                'paginationInput': {
                                                'pageNumber': pageNumber,
                                            },
                                            'sortOrder': 'PricePlusShippingLowest',
                                            'itemFilter':itemFilter})
```

Is it possible to make it retrieve price:
1. in local currency
2. in particular currency,

For example the ebay site gives you approximate price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shuffle siteid parameter.
But much more robust approach is to create currencies rates on Your own, lets say:

```
import numpy as np
eur_rate=4.3008 #EUR to PLN rate
usd_rate=3.9047 #USD to PLN rate
gbp_rate=5.0411 #GBP to PLN rate
a = np.array([["EUR",eur_rate]], dtype=object)
b = [["USD", usd_rate]]
c = [["GBP", gbp_rate]]
curr_rates = np.vstack((a,np.asarray(b,object)))
curr_rates = np.vstack((curr_rates,np.asarray(c,object)))
```

Here is my python repository: https://github.com/Brat-Pit/eBay

Comment: Thank you. Another question - is it possible to get estimate date of delivery of an item?

Comment: Sure: for example GetItem() in Trading API. Drawback: one query for one item only, so it's quite annoying (5k queries daily limit). And another thing: eBay API has a lot of different functions for getting delivery times - from my experience it's very confusing (different dates).